# Subquery returned more than 1 value.how to handle this and get multiple ids

Tags: .net, sql-server, cursor, cursors

```
SET @IdInternalSelection = (
    SELECT iss.IdInternalSelection 
    FROM HesSelection.InternalSelection iss 
    INNER JOIN HesSelection.ExtractedLabInternalSelection2CatPatientActivity cpa 
       ON iss.IdInternalSelection = cpa.IdInternalSelection               
    WHERE cpa.IdCatPatientActivity = @IdCatPatientActivity)
```

I will get output of `IdCatPatientActivity` from another query.

Based on this `IdCatPatientActivity`, I need to set `IdInternalSelection` which fails for some `IdCatPatientActivity` ids.

This is because IdCatPatientActivity is some cases is linked with multiple IdInternalSelection

What i need is to get all the IdInternalSelection associated with IdCatPatientActivity  and then loop each IdInternalSelection and insert it into different table.

I am not getting  multiple IdInternalSelection ids.
Can some one please help me?

Comment: You're most likely thinking the whole thing in a wrong way. You should not code this kind of step-by-step / looping item at the time approach. SQL Server works a lot better with a set based approach.

Comment: since i was little familiar with cursors wanted to go with the same :).thanks for your inputs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the variable is of type TABLE.

```
declare @IdInternalSelection  table
(
    Id varchar(1000)
)

insert into @IdInternalSelection
SELECT iss.IdInternalSelection 
                            FROM HesSelection.InternalSelection iss 
                            INNER JOIN HesSelection.ExtractedLabInternalSelection2CatPatientActivity cpa ON iss.IdInternalSelection = cpa.IdInternalSelection                 
                            WHERE cpa.IdCatPatientActivity = @IdCatPatientActivity
```